# Gradient of two-particle system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, vectors, differentiation

I'm working on problem 5.1a from Griffiths Intro to QM and given that: 
$$\mathbf R \equiv \frac{m_1\mathbf{r_1} + m_2 \bf r_2}{m_1+m_2}$$
and $\bf r \equiv \bf r_1 - \bf r_2$ I need to show that, 
$$\nabla_1 = \frac{m_1\nabla_R}{m_1+m_2}+\nabla_r$$

I started by letting $R$ be function of $X$,$Y$,$Z$ and $r$ a function of $x$,$y$,$z$ so I can take their respective gradients but I'm wondering, what is $\nabla_1$ referring to and how can I show that the expression is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\nabla_1$ refers to the gradient with respect to the first coordinate $\mathbf{r}_1$. I think the most transparent way to do the derivation is to switch to the notation $\partial/\partial\mathbf{r}_1$, then expand the derivative using the multivariable chain rule, and then switch back to the nabla notation:
$$\begin{align}\nabla_1 &\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}_1} \\
&= \frac{\partial\mathbf{R}}{\partial\mathbf{r}_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{R}} + \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial\mathbf{r}_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}} \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}_1}\left(\frac{m_1\mathbf{r}_1 + m_2\mathbf{r}_2}{m_1+m_2}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{R}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}_1}\left(\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}} \\
&= \left(\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{R}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}} \\
&\equiv \left(\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}\right) \nabla_\mathbf{R} + \nabla_\mathbf{r}
\end{align}$$

## Addendum:

The single-variable chain rule basically says that if you have a function $f = f(u)$, where $u = u(x)$, then the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} $$

The generalization to the multi-variable case $f = f(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$, where $u_1 = u_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and so on, is obtained by replacing total derivatives with partial derivatives, and summing over all possible intermediate variables $u_1,\ldots,u_n$: 
$$\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_1} \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_n} \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x_1} \\
 &\vdots \\
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_1} \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_n} + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_n} \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x_n}
\end{align}$$
By writing $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $\mathbf{u} = (u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ as vectors, these equations can be written in a more compact (albeit slightly ambigous) notation:
$$\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}} \cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
\end{align}$$
If we just don't write explicitly what the arbitrary function $f$ is, then we get the multivariable chain rule for differential operators:
$$\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} &= \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{u}}
\end{align}$$
When we have two sets of vectors $\{\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n\}$ and $\{\mathbf{u}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{u}_n\}$, then the chain rule becomes:
$$\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}_1} &= \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}_1}{\partial \mathbf{x}_1} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{u}_1} + \cdots + \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}_n}{\partial \mathbf{x}_1} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{u}_n} \\
 &\vdots \\
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}_n} &= \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}_1}{\partial \mathbf{x}_n} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{u}_1} + \cdots + \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}_n}{\partial \mathbf{x}_n} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{u}_n} \\
\end{align}$$
Or more compactly:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}_i} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}_j}{\partial \mathbf{x}_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{u}_j}$$
This is the version of the chain rule that I used in the derivation above.

Comment: I don't think I've seen the chain rule applied to expand a derivative like that before. Could you explain how you went from the first to second line?

Comment: See the updated answer :)